# efficient way of computing a list with mean of values in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, mean

I need to compute a list with the mean values of another list. To be more precise, the input list have this form:

```
input_list =

['1.538075/42.507325',
 '1.537967/42.507690',
 '1.538292/42.507742',
 '1.538399/42.507376',
 '1.538075/42.507325']
```

And I need to compute a list with the mean of the values before and after the slash ("/"), like this result:

```
desired_output =

[1.5381616, 42.5074916]
```

I can obtain the desired_output correctly using this code:

```
desired_output = pd.Series(input_list)\
                .apply(lambda r: pd.Series(r.split('/')))\
                .astype(float)\
                .mean()\
                .tolist()
```

However, I have a very large number of input lists and the proposed code is somewhat slow, so I need to find a more efficient way to do it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need pandas here, a simple list comprehension should work:

```
input_list = ['1.538075/42.507325',
 '1.537967/42.507690',
 '1.538292/42.507742',
 '1.538399/42.507376',
 '1.538075/42.507325']

from statistics import mean

out = [mean(map(float, x)) for x in zip(*(x.split('/') for x in input_list))]
```

output: `[1.5381616, 42.5074916]`

Or using numpy:

```
np.vstack([np.fromstring(s, sep='/') for s in input_list]).mean(0).tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

`.apply` is the slow part, but luckily Pandas has the `.str` accessor to vectorise string operations. This should be considerably faster:

```py
desired_output = (pd.Series(input_list)
                  .str.split('/', expand=True)
                  .astype(float)
                  .mean()
                  .tolist())
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a numpy array with `dtype=float`, then calculate mean along `axis=0`

```
np.array([s.split('/') for s in input_list], dtype=float).mean(0)
```

---

```
array([ 1.5381616, 42.5074916])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using pandas and comprehensions -

```py
pd.DataFrame([_.split('/') for _ in input_list]).astype(float).mean().to_list()
# [1.5381616, 42.5074916]
```